# URLConnection inputStream not being read fully

Tags: java, response, urlconnection

I wrote the following code for downloading some files from a server but the problem is that this code isn't reading the complete response (inputStream). File size is 7.5 MB while I am getting 5.5 MB each time and of course adobe reader complains that file is damaged. Here is the code

```
import java.net.URLConnection;
public class Downloader {
URL url;
public Downloader(){
    try {

        url = new URL("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/algs4partI/slides%2F13StacksAndQueues.pdf");
        FileOutputStream outStream;
        ObjectOutputStream oStream;
        try {
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            InputStream inStream = con.getInputStream();
            outStream = new FileOutputStream("data.pdf");
            oStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);
            int bytesRead;
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
            while((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){

                //outStream.write(buffer, 0 , bytesRead);
                oStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                buffer = new byte[100000];
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            }
            System.out.println("Total Bytes read are = " + totalBytesRead);
            oStream.close();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Downloader d = new Downloader();
}
```

}

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an `ObjectOutputStream`?

Comment: The actual size of the file is 5,383KB. And removing `ObjectOutputStream` and writing to a `FileInputStream` worked perfectly for me.

Comment: You don't need to create a new buffer after every read. You're just creating work for the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to be using `ObjectOutputStream` when you aren't serializing java objects.

Un-comment the line

```
//outStream.write(buffer, 0 , bytesRead);
```

and remove

```
oStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

So:

```
while((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){

    outStream.write(buffer, 0 , bytesRead);           
    buffer = new byte[100000]; // this line is useless
    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
}
```

Get rid of the `ObjectOutputStream` altogether. Your file is 5.25 MB (5,511,685 bytes) long, not 7.5 MB.

Comment: Once I changed it to FileOutputStream as   you suggested, it worked like a charm ! Bottomline, I got rid of ObjectOutputStream altogether :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Although this does not change the issue at hand, reallocating the byte[] inside the loop serves no purpose.

Comment: Yeah, I had removed that when I ran it too.

Answer (score 1):

`InputStream` that you get from URL connection does not guarantee that all bytes arrive at once. They are transfered over network, so your reading speed may be higher than your network. Method `read()` returns number of bytes that have been read at current execution of the method. If it returns 0 the information is probably not available at the moment but will be available later.

Method `read()` returns -1 to indicate end of stream. Bottom line: change `> 0` in your `if` statement to `>= 0`.

Comment: If `read()` returns -1, the loop will stop. If `read()` returns 0, the  loop will stop. I think he's covered.

Comment: Actually, I think this won't help.  According to the javadoc, the `read` method either returns `-1` or it reads 1 or bytes ... and hence returns a number > 0.

Comment: Continuing @StephenC 's comment, `This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown`. [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[]))

Comment: @StephenC you are right, it didn't help as javadoc says, "If the length of b is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned; otherwise, there is an attempt to read at least one byte. If no byte is available because the stream is at the end of the file, the value -1 is returned; otherwise, at least one byte is read and stored into b." But interestingly, the mystery was with using ObjectOutputStream, needed to use FileOutputStream and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: The only way read() can run zero is if you give it a zero length. It doesn't return zero if 'information is probably not available at the moment'. It blocks until information *is* available. -1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using ObjectOutputStream.  This encodes the output in the Java Object Serialization format, which is not what the PDF reader expects / requires.

Use a plain `FileOutputStream` and it should work.